# Click a TextView in a ListView to open another layout page

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to enable a `textview` on my `listview` clickable and then open another `layout`:

```
  private class IndexListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Index>{
        public IndexListAdapter(){
            super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview_item, index);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent){
            if (view == null)
                view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_item, parent, false);

            Index currentIndex = index.get(position);

            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pName);
            name.setText(currentIndex.getName());

            name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    items.add(new Item(patientTxt.getText().toString(), operatorTxt.getText().toString(),
                            serialTxt.getText().toString(), deviceTxt.getText().toString(), dateTxt.getText().toString(),
                            assetTxt.getText().toString(), locationTxt.getText().toString(), qcTxt.getText().toString()));
                    populateList();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Item.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }
```

what i am trying to do is that I will have one item which is a name to show on a `listview_item` or a list tab and when I click on the name it will open up another `layout` or page to display another list of items.

Comment: what is the problem you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call like this in your custom adapter so you will try like this it will work

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Item.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
```

You will change into this.
**You just send the context and using that one call the intent**

```
 Intent i = new Intent(mContext, TabActivityPacs.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            i.putExtra("STUDY", study);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you not able to get click event of `TextView`

add this attribute for your `TextView`

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

also add

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

for your ListView